# How to view output from manually loaded kernel extension (kext)?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, kernel-extension

I have followed the tutorial at
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptKEXT/kext_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002365-BABJHCJA
to create a kernel extension (kext).

Basically the relevant code is this

```
kern_return_t MyKext_start (kmod_info_t * ki, void * d)
{
    printf("MyKext has started.\n");
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have succesfully loaded the kext (as shown by kextstat):

```
$ kextstat | grep MyKext
  153    0 0xffffff7f846fc000 0x2000     0x2000     com.example.MyKext (1) 97D9903E-3CB5-3D3C-A7B0-4EF5AF8CB575 <4>
```

How can I view the `printf` output? Should it not be visible when loading the kext?

Using Xcode 8.2.1 on macOS 10.12.3.

Comment: How are you loading the `kext` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The output will be in the system log, prefixed with "kernel: " (Console.app, or `syslog` on the command line.)

Comment: Looking for output for long time and with your help finally found it. Thank you for the answer!